# centering shortcode in WP template

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a part of my WP template that contains a shortcode - however, it aligns left instead of center no matter what tricks I try. 
It's a simple countdown timer where I pipe in a date variable. I figured it's a simple setting to get CSS to work, but I'm running my head against a wall here.

Any guesses?

```
echo '<div class="countdown-wrapper">';
echo do_shortcode("[circularcountdown endDate=\"$date3\"]");
echo '</div>';
```

from the css:

```
.countdown-wrapper {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks!

Example: [www.stonecalendar.com/dbstuff](http://www.stonecalendar.com/dbstuff)

Comment: Using an `auto` margin on `inline-block`s makes no sense. Try removing  `display: inline-block;` and specifying a width other(=less) than `100%`

Comment: You will need to show us an example of this happening (either a jsfiddle or a link to your site)

Comment: http://stonecalendar.com/dbstuff/ uses the template, which inserts the countdown element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
.countdown-wrapper {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I tried pasting that into my CSS, with no result.

Comment: Hi @Lars, make sure it comes after any other .countdown-wrapper styles you have set up, or append !important to the end of each part to make sure it is taking effect as you expect. What is your site URL exactly?

Comment: Hi Peter, I got it working, no worries :) The site URL is Stonecalendar.com - currently a work in progress, but getting there.

Comment: Hey @Lars I have just looked at your site and on smaller browser screens that solution of the position: relative; left: 300px; doesn't work well as it ends up being cut off the page. If you use my solution above this won't occur. Try going on the site and resizing your browser to see...

Comment: Yup, well aware of that - I'm going to switch to %'s as soon as I get a moment to update the CSS :) 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect mate... Just wanted to make sure :-) good luck ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

```
.countdown-wrapper {
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't get any results from the suggestions.

If you want to see it in action, it's added here:

http://stonecalendar.com/dbstuff/

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the shortcode is outputting is likely to be a block-level element.

You can still do this in the container, but you'll need to give it a fixed width and not display it as `inline-block`:

```
.countdown-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Replace the `200px` with the width of the element within.

If it's a variable width you'll probably need to amend the styles of the generated markup directly.